# Function not returning value despite entering if statement for termination leetcode c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ8gN.png)

This is the entire code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int canCompleteCircuit(vector<int>& gas, vector<int>& cost) {
        
        int n=gas.size();
        int temp, flag;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            temp=0;
            flag=0;
            cout<<"i: "<<i;
            for(int j=i;j!=i || flag==0;j++){
                
                if(j==n && i==0)
                    break;
                if(j==n)
                    j=0;
                if(j==i)
                    flag=1;
                
                temp=temp+gas[j];
                temp=temp-cost[j];
                cout<<" J: "<<j<<" Temp: "<<temp<<endl;
                if(temp<0 && j!=n-1){
                    i=j;
                    break;
                }
                if(temp<0)
                    break;
            }
            if(temp>=0){
                cout<<"HI"<<endl;
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

The question is leetcode 134 for reference.

I tried printing a dummy statement to check if the code was entering the termination if statement which it was. But for some reason the code doesn't return i and instead continues with the execution of the loop. I tried putting a break statement after return i as well and it still didn't break the loop.

Comment: Could you please explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how the nested loop is supposed to stop?

Comment: Also, a question should be self-contained (what is "leetcode 134"?) and present a [mre].

Comment: I guess something is repeatedly calling the function, so you do leave it but you reenter it immediately. Try adding a dummy output at the start of the function.

Comment: I have put a dummy output at the start of the function and it is being called twice which means the function is calling itself after returning i.

Comment: You are just confused by the fact that LeetCode runs more than one test case. You can see those test cases configured in the user-interface of LeetCode. I guess this question can now be closed; it is expected.

Comment: And you can't resolve this problem with your debugger? If you don't know how to use the debugger, this is the perfect time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop in the posted code tries to traverse both vectors from the index `j = i` to their ends and then from their beginnings up to index `i` again. It uses a perhaps convoluted logic and introduces a variable `flag` to ensure a single pass, but there is (at least) an issue that causes an infinite loop in some cases.

```
if(temp<0 && j!=n-1){
   i=j;                // <---- 
   break;
}
```

When the algorithm is checking the elements *before* the starting index `i`, the value of `j` is clearly *less* than `i`, so that the outer loop gets stuck.

Consider a *single* loop instead, which traverses both the vectors *once* and  stores in a variable how much fuel is needed to arrive to that point from the beginning of the travel.